# Result of plotting a straight line does not look straight

Tags: r, ggplot2

When plotting a straight line from (0, 0) to (0.00856390, 1), the resulting plot (I use RStudio) does not display a straight line. Is there a way (e.g. by changing some settings?) of ensuring that the resulting line looks straight?

Some code:

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

DT = data.table(xval = c(0, 0.00856390),
                yval = c(0, 1))

ggplot(DT, aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + 
  geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),
                     breaks = c(0, 1))
```

And the result (the line has three 'kinks' in it):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried exporting it to a png with large enough DPI and size?

Comment: If you remove the third point from this question, you will avoid comments like "but of course it isn't straight, you are plotting two different lines!"

Comment: Can't reproduce, it's straight for we. Can you try exporting plot to a pdf and checking if it's straight there?

Comment: OK, that was indeed confusing. I removed the third point

Comment: The problem is related to the start-stop xval of the line, see my answer for more details.

Comment: @PoGibas, it looks straight when I export to pdf, although the thickness of the line does not seem heterogeneous. I actually plot everything with RMarkdown in html. I suppose I can try importing the pdf file via RMarkdown (never tried such a thing).

Comment: Don't import `pdf`,  when plotting (rendering) to html set `dev` to `pdf`. https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Guessing you're aware of this, but want to cover all the bases: if you're looking for a vertical line, you're not going to get one, since those points aren't perpendicular to the x-axis. But if you just want a straight line, then it's just a matter of how you export. You may or may not get a straight-looking line in the viewer. The render depends on your computer's/monitor's settings and capabilities. And ggplot2's graphics outputs are rather finicky.

But if you export the graph, just make sure to do it at a high enough quality and your line will come out looking straight, as others have mentioned. I exported to pdf using the following and the line is straight even though it's not straight in my viewer:

```
setwd("c:\\")    

DT = data.table(xval = c(0, 0.00856390),
    yval = c(0, 1))

DTplot <- ggplot(DT, aes(x = xval, y = yval)) + 
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1),
        breaks = c(0, 1))

ggsave(DTplot, filename = "test.pdf", device = cairo_pdf, 
    width = 4, height = 3, units = "in")
```

Really, the export is all that matters because nobody is going to see the chart on your screen other than yourself.

Comment: I actually did not realize that it is only the way I export that matters. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

user3603486's answer made me realize I could simply use the dpi setting in RMarkDown when generating the figure. I realize now (but not at the time) that I should have added that I generate my figures in RMarkDown. With `dpi = 500`, the lines look straight.

The code for this looks like:

````
```{r echo=FALSE, fig.height=2.7, dpi=500}

ggplot_object

```
````